# Passings Strings to server - Java GUI

Tags: java, string, sockets, user-interface

I am having a problem passing Strings to a server / client simple example pay system. Basically I can pass double/s however I would like to send and recieve the Employee name also this is my code and it doesn't work, can anyone help or suggest something, thank you

MY CODE:

```
if (e.getSource() == calculate) {
    try {
       //Get the employee name, employee id, payrate & hours from the text fields
       String empname = jtfEname.getText();

       double empid = Double.parseDouble(jtfEid.getText().trim());
       double payrate = Double.parseDouble(jtfPayRate.getText().trim());
       double hours = Double.parseDouble(jtfHours.getText().trim());

       //send the employee name, employee id, payrate & hours to the server

       outputToServer.writeString(empname);
       outputToServer.writeDouble(empid);
       outputToServer.writeDouble(payrate);
       outputToServer.writeDouble(hours);
       outputToServer.flush();

       //Get pay from the server
       double pay = inputFromServer.readDouble();

       //Display to the text area
       jta.append("Employee Name is " + jtfEname + "\n");
       jta.append("Employee ID is " + jtfEid + "\n");
       jta.append("PayRate is " + jtfPayRate + "\n");
       jta.append("Hours is " + jtfHours + "\n");
       jta.append("Pay received from the server is " + pay + '\n');
       jtfPayRate.setText("");
       jtfHours.setText("");
   }
```

Comment: How to does the server work?

Comment: What is `outputToServer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

Then you can simply use the `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` methods:

```
// Client: send String
DataOutputStream out = ...;
out.writeUTF("Some string");

// Server: receive String
DataInputStream in = ...;
String text = in.readUTF();
```

Comment: Spot on, well explained and executed perfect result. Thank you kindly for the help Have a Aweseome day!!!